# Are there any flights from London to Blackpool?

Tags: air-travel, uk, london

I am rather confused here, it looks like Blackpool Airport has been shut down according to Google but Wikipedia states that the airport is still there.

Also there are results from Skyscanner and Google. What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: The airport has been reopen on December but services is limited

Comment: @Him any flights to/from London?

Comment: @User - Can I ask.. Why do you need to take a flight? Surely other transport methods (Train, Coach) might be more suited? Unless there is a time specific reason..

Comment: @Phorce kids get tired when we travel using our car and my other half never flew in her entire life and I want her to try traveling by air

Comment: Wikipedia says that as of December 2014 the airport is open but has no commercial service. Hence no flights to London or anywhere unless you own a plane or charter one. Any reason to think this isn't correct?

Comment: @User Would it not be better to fly to Manchester / Liverpool and take a short distance train to Blackpool? Looking at your post, Isle of man looks like the only place to get one from

Comment: @Phorce It's to test-run a movie plot involving body armour, a de-activated bazooka and a gold bar.

Comment: @Phorce If you are coming from london then IMO by the time you have added the airport BS to the time it takes to get from Manchester or Liverpool to blackpool by train you may as well just make the whole journey by train.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [the airport's website](http://blackpoolairport.com/), the only scheduled services are:

> [Citywing](http://www.citywing.com/cgi-bin/airkiosk/I7/181002i?NM=2&LANG=EN) operating flights between Blackpool, the Isle of Man and Belfast

Comment: Update: as of [March 2017](http://www.citywingnews.com/citywing-statement/), Citywing was no longer in operation.